# How to get rid of storing repetition of same character in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I want to Calculate number of occurence of characters in a string and I calculate it in this way:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string msg;
        int count=0;
        int counter= 1; 
        char[] array=new char[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter any string");
        msg = Console.ReadLine();
        array = msg.ToCharArray();
        Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
        for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
        {
            count = 1;
            for (int j = counter; j < array.Length; j++)
            {

                if (array[i] == array[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            counter++;
            char[] storing = new char[array.Length];


            if (storing.Contains<char>(array[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} already count", array[i]);
            }
            else
                {
                   storing[i] = array[i];
                   Console.WriteLine("{0} Come {1} times",storing[i],count); 
                }
            }
            }
```

but problem is that this storing array store all characters, and I want that when a character come it checks this storing array already have this character or not if no then store it and for this reason I use Contains method but it does'nt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your “storing” array *inside* your for loop, this means that each time you check Contains, your array is empty. Consider moving the declaration of the array above the outer for loop.

I would also suggest that storing your already checked characters in a [HashSet<char>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better choice than an array.

It would change your code to look something like this:

```
var storing = new HashSet<char>();

for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
    if (!storing.Add(array[i]))
        continue;

    count = 1;
    for (int j = counter; j < array.Length; j++
    {
        if (array[i] == array[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: This is also true.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott Perham, your first advise work perfectly as I expected. I never use HasahSet but I am trying to use it also.

Answer (score 1):

A [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably a better data structure to use. Your key would be the character you are reading, and the value would be the occurrence count.

A quick example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ... do your normal setup "enter string etc"
        Console.WriteLine(array.Length);

        Dictionary<char, int> charToOccurencesMappings = str.ToCharArray().GroupBy(s => s).Select(g => new Occurences { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Count);

        foreach (var mapping in charToOccurencesMappings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.Key} occured {mapping.Value} times");
        }
    }
}

public class Occurences
{
    public char Key { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public Occurences()
    {
    }
}
```

The wonders of [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq).

Comment: I think you mean "Occurrences".